# How to change the database field orders in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

In zend project I fetch data from the database and show in a table. It shows data in the same order as stored in the database. But I want to show the fileds in diffeent order than in database order. But I don't know how to do thid. Here I means field order not the row order.
Please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say how youre displaying but lets assume you have made Table Classes for each table i would do something like this:

```
<?php foreach $zendDbRowObject->getTable()->getDisplayOrder() as $fieldName): ?>
    <?php echo $zendDbRowObject->$fieldName; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So then in your Table clas for a particular table you can create a property/method to get the fields in the order you want them in:

```
public function getDisplayOrder() {
   // fake column names obviously... use yours here.
   return array(
      'column5',
      'column1',
      'column4',
      'column2',
      'column3'
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do db select, you can select the coloumns that you want, so instead of select *,

you do select col5,col3,col2,col6,col1 from tablename

This will change the order of the columns

$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('t' => 'table'),
                    array('t.col2', 'p.col1`'));

Comment: I new all the fields but in different order